# Add Existing Form To Project Causes Intellitrace To Crash

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, intellitrace

I am creating a new project that requires 4 or 5 forms that have already been created in previous projects.

I added them by right clicking on the project -> add existing -> browse to form and add Form.cs, form.Designer.cs, and Form.resx

I went in and changed the namespace on the form.

Now when I try to run the project in debug mode, IntelliTrace crashes.

The program opens, but takes like 5 minutes to stop "Running" in VS after I close it.

I'm 95% sure the only thing that can be the cause of this is my adding the forms to the project.  What have I done wrong here?

**EDIT :** When I try to open the added forms, they won't open. There is no error or anything, they just won't open.

When I debug IntelliTrace

```
StackOverFlow Exception was unahndled
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
```

Comment: This by definition is a bug in something, because 'crash' in some respect means 'doesn't present intelligent behaviour to the user'. Are you running any add-ins or extensions? I'd be more suspicious of those than of raw Visual Studio. Try a fresh install on a clean machine, loading the same solution?

Comment: Not running anything else...it comes up and says "APPCRASH" for Intellitrace..I guess I'll just have to recreate all those forms

Answer (score 1):

You may have a bad setting somewhere.

This will reset all your VS settings:

> devenv /ResetSettings

Comment: what an awfull answer. "you" may have any kind of issue. This is appropriate as a comment at best!!!!!